# Multi For loop php

Tags: php

How to use multi for loop with array.

I'm trying to iterate over the contents of an array.
This is the code I have tried.

```php
<?php

$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];

for($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++){
    echo $arr[$i];
    for($j = 0; $j < $i; $j++){
        echo $arr[$j];
    }
    echo "<br />";
}
echo "<br/>";
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($arr); $i++){
    if ($i%3 == 0){
        echo $arr[$i-1] . "  " . "<br />";
    } else {
        echo $arr[$i-1] . "  ";
    }
}
```

this is the result i got

```
1
2 1
3 1 2
4 1 2 3
5 1 2 3 4

1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
10 11 12
13 14 15
```

I want to display a result like this and how it works:

```
1 
2  3
4  5  6
7  8  9  10
11 12 13 14 15

1 | 6 | 11
2 | 7 | 12
3 | 8 | 13
4 | 9 | 14
5 | 10 | 15
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two separate questions:

The first one, I'd do like this:

```
$arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15];
$prev =0;
for ($i=1; $i<=5; $i++) {  
   print implode(" ", array_slice($arr, $prev, $i)) . "<br>\n";
   $prev += $i;
}
```

You could replace the array_slice() with a for loop if that makes you happier. The second one:

```
$cols = 3;
$rows = floor(count($arr)/$cols);

for ($i = 0; $i < $rows; $i++) {
  for ($j=0; $j<=$cols; $j++) {
    print $arr[$i+$j*$rows] ?? ' ';
    if ($j < ($cols-1)) print " | ";
  }
  print "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks very much. It works. But why should use floor on `$rows`.

Comment: check here why https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php

Comment: I just wanted $rows to be an integer, but it should work fine without it.